# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory , WHY?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, java-home

I have set JAVA_HOME in my system

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Users\Yazan\Downloads\jdk-19.0.2
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
> location of your Java installation.

in android studio and I get error I'm restart the device but the same problem stay.

[image]

Comment: can you make sure the path, also extract if it zip

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've extracted the zip, and it will look like

[image]